# Restricting customers to max of (some number) purchases for a certain product in Magento

Tags: magento2.2, products, quantity, rules

Is there any good modules out there that can handle this? Or would this be a custom event / observer that needs to be written?

Here's an image on a non magento site that shows specifically what i'm looking for.

[image]

Magento 2.2.3 EE

This needs to work with the Magento commerce b2b module. So everyone in a group/company would be limited. If there was 4 people in the group but one person purchased the max amount then the other 3 would not be allowed to purchase any. This makes it increasingly more complex and difficult logic.

Answer (score 2):

You need write your custom module and you have to use this event (**sales_quote_item_qty_set_after**).

in this event you need to 
- check current logged user and get all items that the customer purchanesed during current month.
- check the QTY of your product, and if the qty is excedded the maximum qty, you need to throw expection

```
throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException( __('The most you may purchase is %1.',$_qty));
```

you can also add message to the item itslef

```
$quoteItem->getQuote()->addErrorInfo(
        'stock',
        'cataloginventory',
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Data::ERROR_QTY,
        __('Please correct the quantity for some products.')
        );
```

where the $quoteItem coming from this code

```
$quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();
```

I had  before a similarlogic and this work for me

Comment: Thanks for the response, I forgot to mention this needs to work with the Magento commerce b2b module. So everyone in a group/company would be limited. If there was 4 people in the group but one person purchased the max amount then the other 3 would not be allowed to purchase any. This makes it increasingly more complex and difficult logic.

Comment: I believe that you can manage it in this event but you need do check the customer company then you get all items qty for all 4 people (as in your example)

Comment: Any more updates @WISAMHAKIM, i'm very interested.

Comment: hello @getData, did you try the logic in the second comment ?

Comment: @WISAMHAKIM what should be the files the above logic is placed in?

Comment: the file is not exist you have to build new module, in this module you need to create observer file to trigger this event [sales_quote_item_qty_set_after], please have a look at this file to know how you can use this event, app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Item.php. you can also read this blog [https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/use-event-magento-2/]

Comment: Are you allowing guests to purchase as well or registered users only?

Comment: @ShawnAbramson registered users only.